# Use multithreading to count?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am just starting to use multi-threading, and I am trying to build a console application that starts to count with 2 different threads when the user hits the Enter key, and stops counting when the Enter key is pressed a second time, and then outputs the count for both threads (I realize that with my code, these will be 2 different numbers). I set this up, but for some reason, one of the numbers is usually negative.There is also quite a bit of a delay before I receive count output. Why am I getting negative counts, why is the delay so long, and how can I correct this?
My code so far;

```
    class Program
{


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        System.Threading.Thread threadA = new Thread(ThreadA);
        System.Threading.Thread threadB = new Thread(ThreadB);

        Console.WriteLine("Once you press enter, this application will count as high as it can until you press enter again.");
        ConsoleKeyInfo info = Console.ReadKey();
        if (info.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
        {
            threadA.Start();
            threadB.Start();
        }     
    }

    private static bool continueCounting = true;

    static void ThreadA()
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue ; i++)
        {
            count++;
        }
        ConsoleKeyInfo info2 = Console.ReadKey();

        if (info2.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)

        continueCounting = false;
        Console.WriteLine(count);
    }

    static void ThreadB()
    {
        int count = 0;
        while (continueCounting)
        {
            count++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(count);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use multithreading?  Counting sequentially means that each iteration to increase a number as to be done [atomically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability) so you can't do anything in parallel.  For example ThreadB can't increment from 1 to 2 until ThreadA increments 0 to 1.  So now ThreadA is waiting for ThreadB to increment from 1 to 2 so it can increment from 2 to 3.  All that waiting means you gain nothing (probably a loss in performance).

Comment: ContinueCounting isn't volatile (meaning thread won't notice it changing for a while (or ever). Also threadb counter can overflow, going negative for a couple of seconds.

Comment: You don't actually check the keyboard until you have reached looping to `int.MaxValue`.  That explains why it takes so long.

Comment: Oh, dang, I see your point... how can I make it so that it checks BEFORE max value(or just keeps counting)? And prevent overflow on thread B?

Comment: Counting isn't a very useful job for multithreading. (Truth be told, there are far fewer good jobs for multithreading than you'd think.) Good candidates have sub-jobs that can take a while to do, aren't memory-bound, and make sense to do at the same time, Otherwise you don't get a return on all the work you have to do to keep the threads from breaking everything to hell. If you want to practice, you'd be better off having one thread count, and the other wait for input and tell the first thread when to stop.

Comment: I understand multithreading isn't the best option for this, it is just an exercise to try to understand it better.

Comment: @MJ65476 why don't you check the input and set `continueCounting` in Main()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> one of the numbers is usually negative

That's because there was no limit guard on the `ThreadB` loop.  It was entirely possible for `count` to reach `MaxValue` then wrap around to negative maxvalue.

I also put all keyboard checks in your main thread where they arguably should be.  It is here that we set `continueCounting` to `false` when the second enter key is pressed.

I also made `continueCounting` `volatile` as it is being used by multiple threads and its value should not be CPU optimised/cached.

Try this code, this fixes the delay you were experiencing; allows both threads to count at once; and exit ASAP when the enter key is pressed.

```
class Program
{
    #region Static fields

    private static volatile bool continueCounting = true;

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var threadA = new Thread(ThreadA);
        var threadB = new Thread(ThreadB);

        Console.WriteLine(
            "Once you press enter, this application will count as high as it can until you press enter again.");
        var info = Console.ReadKey();
        if (info.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
        {
            threadA.Start();
            threadB.Start();
        }

        info = Console.ReadKey();
        if (info.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
        {
            continueCounting = false;
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void ThreadA()
    {
        var count = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < int.MaxValue && continueCounting; i++)
        {
            count++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"A: {count}");
    }

    static void ThreadB()
    {
        var count = 0;
        while (continueCounting && count < int.MaxValue)
        {
            count++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"B: {count}");
    }

    #endregion
}
```